# How to show data from external api to theme template?

Tags: 8

I am totally new to Drupal. I have given one assignment to build Drupal site which shows courses from our company site. I am totally stuck in one point. I need to show data from our api into theme template.

Can you please guide me on this? If you have any example, please share with me. I will dig into it and I will try to solve my problem.

Comment: First of all I would not create a template for this unless absolutely necessary. There are so many options depending on your specific needs. Please narrow it a little. For instance just a shot in the dark, try to populate a custom table with the data and use Views to display it. [`hook_views_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) Will allow Views access to the custom table.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers to that question, and it depends on the design (appearence and behaviors), but the Drupal foundation is usually the same.

**1st step**

Create a custom block and place it in a page (node of a generic type is a good option or a programmatically created page.
**OR**
Create a custom page (see ´hook_menu´)

**2nd step**

Create a custom theme function using ´hook_theme´ (template file is usually easier to maintain)

**3rd step (connect to the API)**

Due to performance considerations (async vs. sync request) I prefer to use JavaScript to get the data and present it on the page / block we created. (AngularJS is my friend..)
If JS is not an option, then you can make the request in ´hook_block_view´ in case you used custom block, ´hook_page_build´ or in your ´hook_menu´'s callback in case you chose a page in step 1.

Comment: You should note that this would be a good option (3rd step) if the data retrieved from  the API changes on a frequent basis. Otherwise, say it changes every few months or so, you should probably save the data to your server to make use of all the cache options.

Comment: This case is way more advanced and involves using Drupal's cache API with or wo custom entity or content type, maybe even cron task.. :) This case deserves another thread

Comment: I'll prefer 3rd option.But my issue is my block is not loading. I want show data in grid format. But $view->result is empty in 
template_preprocess_views_view function of theme.inc, hence it is not even loading empty block.

Comment: Those are not 3 options, those are 3 steps. Why are you using Views? How do you retrieve the data with a view? Or are you just using View's theme function??